# Swipe in viewpager and EditText validation

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am developing an app where the user can type in stuff in edittexts and get to the next view by swiping the screen. The swiping-stuff is handled by a viewpager.

**What I want to do is the following:**

The user should only be able to swipe when all edittexts are filled. Currently all my edittexts have an TextWatcher whichs sets a boolean value to "true" once every field is filled. When it is true, I can enable the viewpager, when it isn't, I can disable it.

What is missing is that the user doesn't get feedback if a field is empty, the view simply doesn't swipe, but the user might not know why. What I need is to show a textmessage if he tries to swipe the page, stating that at least one edittext is still empty.

I thought about adding the viewpager to a gesture detector - would that be a good idea? If yes, how would I implement that the best way possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can notify the user by showing the first incomplete field. There is already a good method for this: `EditText.setError()`.

```
editText.setError("Field is required");
editText.requestFocus();
```

If you want to detect when the swipe occurs, you can use [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) callback interface:

```
abstract void    onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
// Called when the scroll state changes.
abstract void    onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
// This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled, either as part of a    
// programmatically initiated smooth scroll or a user initiated touch scroll.
abstract void    onPageSelected(int position)
// This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
```

The method `onPageScrolled` should be what you are after.

Comment: I know of this method, but I only want to show it when the user tries to swipe to the next page and not all fields are required. How can I do that?

Comment: Thank you for that, but if the required fields are empty, how can I prevent the viewpager to scroll (further)?

Comment: You can use `mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However now I have another problem: When I swipe and not all required fields are filled, I disable the viewpager. Then however the page is still scrolled slightly to the direction I swiped it. When I swipe forward, I can circumvent that problem by setting mViewPager.scrollBy(-positionOffsetPixels, 0); When I swipe to the page before, it doesn't work as it should, since the value of positionOffsetPixels corresponds to the size of the screen in pixels. I don't think I can distinguish between swiping forward or backward?